# check to see if sprite is moving

Tags: sprite-kit, avaudioplayer, cmmotionmanager

I have an app in which I move a node around using the motionManager.gravity

This is my code

```
self.motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
    self.motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 0.005f;

    self.motionQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    self.motionQueue.name = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier] stringByAppendingString:@".motion"];



    self.updatePosition = NO;

    [self.motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:self.motionQueue withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error) {


        @synchronized(self) {
            NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

            [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

            [formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];

            [formatter setRoundingMode: NSNumberFormatterRoundUp];


            {


                numberString = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:motion.gravity.x / 20.0 *200]];
                numberStringy = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:motion.gravity.y / 20.0 *200]];
                n = [numberString intValue];

                /*NSLog(@"ball.center x:%d",n);*/
                y = [numberStringy intValue];

                /*NSLog(@"ball.center y:%f",balla.center.y);*/

            }
            self.gravity = motion.gravity;
            self.updatePosition = YES;
        }
    }];
```

then I use displayLink to update and move the sprite node.  Everything is working great and I can have the node stop at the edges and at specific places on the screen.  What I want to know is if there is a way to see is the node is moving or is stopped:
1. at an edge
2. at a specific place by code.
3. the device is being held level and thus the accelerometer is no generating any 
n or y number greater than 0.

I want to play a sound when the sprite node is moving but stop the sound when the sprite node is not moving.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

[SKPhysicsBody](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsBody/resting) has a property called `resting`. Use that to test for movement.

```
if(myNode.physicsBody.resting) {
    // node is not moving
} else {
    // node is moving
}
```

You can also use the `velocity` property if you want to check only a certain axis for movement.